# Match substring against Azure EasyTables entry with NSPredicate?

Tags: ios, sql, swift, azure, nspredicate

I have an iOS (Swift 4) project set up and synced against an Azure EasyTables database (set up with Azure Mobile App QuickStart).

I'm trying to return database results based on matches against a substring of a row entry in my table:

The "members" column in the table is a string containing group member IDs separated by semicolons, and I want to query all table entries whose "members" field contains the currently signed in user's ID.

Hence, because I know that 'userID' will be a substring of some of my entries' "members" fields, I am querying my database with an NSPredicate with the keyword 'CONTAINS' in the following way:

`NSPredicate(format: "members CONTAINS[cd] %@", userID )`

But the query retrieves no results, even though userID is clearly a substring of several "members" fields. Where am I going wrong here?

Complete function for larger context:

```
// Retrieve all groups 'user' is member of from database and return them in closure
func getGroups(forUser user: SSUser, closure: @escaping ([SSGroup]?) -> Void) {
    var groups : [SSGroup]?
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "members CONTAINS[cd] %@", user.userID )
    self.groupsTable.read(with: predicate) { (result, error) in
        if let err = error {
            print("ERROR: ", err)
        } else if let res = result {
            groups = []
            if let items = res.items {
                for item in items {
                    let group = SSGroup(groupID: item["id"] as? String, name: item["name"] as! String, isPublic: item["isPublic"] as! Bool)
                    print("retrieved group", group.name)
                    groups?.append(group)
                }
            }
        }
        closure(groups)
    }
}
```